# Ao clicar em um link, fechar todas as divs abertas e abrir uma específica?

Tags: javascript, jquery, div

Estou desenvolvendo um site que vai ser apenas uma página e não vai ter rolagem, preciso que quando eu clicar em um < a> feche a div aberta e abra a que passei no href="" do < a>.

Comment: Está utilizando algum framwork de front end como AngularJs, Knockout ou ember?

Comment: Legal. Mas o que você tentou até o momento?

Comment: duplicada de várias perguntas... desta talvez: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2365/como-esconder-um-sub-menu-vis%C3%ADvel-ao-clicar-em-outro-menu-em-js/2366#2366

Comment: Essa pergunta não te ajuda? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25611/criar-um-menu-accordion-apenas-com-css

Comment: Não cara, não pode ser com focus, vai ser touch.

Comment: Eduardo, sem colocar o seu HTML esta pergunta fica muito geral e vai ser fechada como duplicada daquilo que fôr mais parecido.

Answer (score -1):

faz algo tipo assim... quando clicar na div, da um hide nela ( display:none ) e nas outras vc da um show ( display: block )

```
$( "a" ).click(function({
   this.hide(); // ou this.css( 'display', 'none' );
   $( "#outrasDIVs" ).show(); // ou $( "#outrasDIVs" ).css( 'display', block );
}));
```

Comment: Tenho de votar `-1` porque `this.hide();` vai dar erro, e porque `"#outrasDIVs"` não faz muito sentido uma vez que ID's têm de ser unicas: e porque devia ser ao contrário. Esconder todas menos uma.