# Ocultar submenu ao clicar em outro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria que quando clicasse em um item com submenu, o que estivesse ativo se ocultasse.

Encontrei um [script similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2365/como-esconder-um-sub-menu-vis%C3%ADvel-ao-clicar-em-outro-menu-em-js) ao meu, mas tive dificuldades para adaptar.

Estou utilizando o seguinte script para o submenu com onclick

> Javascript para DropDown

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(".abre-dropdown").click(function(){
        $j(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
    })
    $j("ul").click(function(p){
        p.stopPropagation();
    })

    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    var checkbox = $('#btn-menu'); 
    $('body').click(function() { 
    checkbox.prop("checked", false); 
    }); 
    $('#btn-menu, .menuMobile, .barra-menu').click(function(event) { 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    });
```

> HTML do menu :

```
<nav class="menuMobile">
<ul>
    <li class="item-menu-escuro"><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/home"><label style="float:left;" class="icon-home"></label>Página inicial</a></li>
    <li class="abre-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><label style="float:left;" class="icon-location"></label>Nossa casa<label class="icon-down-dir"></label></a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
            <li class="abre-dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><label style="float:left;" class="icon-home"></label>Sobre nós<label class="icon-down-dir"></label></a>
                <ul class="submenu-2">
                    <li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/nossa-casa#terreiro">A casa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/nossa-casa#mae-maria">Mãe Maria C.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/nossa-casa#ogans">Ogans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/nossa-casa#filhos">Filhos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/agenda"><label style="float:left;" class="icon-calendar"></label>Agenda</a></li>
<li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/localizacao"><label style="float:left;" class="icon-location"></label>Localização</a></li>
<li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/contato"><label style="float:left;" class="icon-phone"></label>Contato</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thiago tente implementar esse código:

```
$j(".abre-dropdown a").click(function() {
  var item = $(this).parent();
  $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').not($(this).parent('li').children('ul')).slideUp();
  item.children('ul').slideToggle();
})
```

#### Exemplo

Clique nos itens em negrito.

```js
$('li a').click(function() {
  var item = $(this).parent();
  $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').not($(this).parent('li').children('ul')).slideUp();
  item.children('ul').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1. item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><b>2. item</b></a>
    <ul class="hide" >
      <li><a href="#"> 2.1. item</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#"> 2.2. item</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#"> <b>2.3. item</b></a>
        <ul class="hide" >
          <li><a href="#"> 2.3.1. item</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> 2.3.2. item</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> 2.3.3. item</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">3. item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4. item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><b>5. item</b></a>
    <ul class="hide" >
      <li><a href="#"> <b>5.1. item</b></a>  
        <ul class="hide" >
          <li><a href="#"> 5.1.1. item</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> 5.1.2. item</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> 5.1.3. item</a> </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="#"> <b>5.2. item</b></a>  
        <ul class="hide" >
          <li><a href="#"> 5.2.1. item</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> 5.2.2. item</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> 5.2.3. item</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> 5.3. item</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Não sei se implementei de forma correta. O que fiz foi substituir o que voce passou por uma parte similar, e assim continuou da mesma forma. Depois adicionei abaixo do que já existia, e ao clicar o submenu desceu e subiu automaticamente..

Comment: @ThiagoBarros. O certo era substituir mesmo, teria como prepapar um JsFiddle, com um funcionamento semelhante ao do seu site? Ficaria mais fácil.

Comment: Estou tentando criar o JsFiddle, mas não está funcionando o script para que apareça o submenu com click.. O código que estou tentando utilizar no JsFiddle é o mesmo que está na pergunta.

Comment: @ThiagoBarros, olhe esse exemplo.. Lhe serve?

Comment: Eu tentei adicionar um segundo nivel de submenu. Porém, quando clicado, todo o menu se oculta novamente.. como eu poderia adicionar mais níveis? O meu javascript entende todos subsmenus, mas não tem a função para ocultar um quando o outro está ativo..

Comment: @ThiagoBarros, entendi. Vou corrigir isso e lhe aviso.

Comment: Tudo bem! Agradeço!

Comment: @ThiagoBarros, olhe a edição. Imagino que agora sirva. rsrs

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado pela ajuda, é exatamente o que imaginei! Agora resta-me adaptar ao meu menu! Parabéns ;)